# Initialize Typescript interface temp objects with all default property values

Tags: typescript

I have an interface -

```
export interface ITreeNode {
    values: string[];
    key: string;
    isSubHeader?: boolean;
    hours?: number[];
    children?: ITreeNode[];
}
```

I want to create a temporary object of this interface and then sequentially assign values to it's properties from different sources.

This does not work since it says `cannot assign value to property 'key' of undefined` -

```
    let node: ITreeNode;
    node.key = "Something";
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally you should create this object as a single object literal. That way the value really is of the specified type from the start (you need to assign only the mandatory properties) :

```
let node:ITreeNode = {
    values: [],
    key: "A"
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBUphgA5CAEzwG8BYAKDmbgDdMAbAV2AGcAuOLxhRkAcwDaAXQDcjFnADWwAJ6DhopGLlMWCXgGUuAIwASwTNSgB+QcYgQOFpDoUALCFyi9bcJFwBbYzRpVxZsNwQOShIkXyIScipgUMYAX0ZGJ3gkZP4E0gpqOABeOHpdZnZuPkFpABp5FmU1OAAiAEE29KA)

If this is not possible, you can initialize the object with an empty object and use a type assertion, but the value will not be in agreement with the type, so it is up to you to make sure the initialization process sets all required properties:

```
let node:ITreeNode = { } as ITreeNode
node.key = "A"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQBUphgA5CAEzwG8BYAKDmbgDdMAbAV2AGcAuOLxhRkAcwDaAXQDcjFnADWwAJ6DhopGLlMWCXgGUuAIwASwTNSgB+QcYgQOFpDoUALCFyi9bcJFwBbYzRpVxZsNwQOShIkXyIScipgUMYAX0ZGJ3gkZP4E0gpqOABeOBo4NLhMXgJiQuTGXOoAOmUVUrgAIgBBLqA)